# Implementing Icomparable Interface for generic class

Tags: .net, generics, compareto, icomparable

I am not able to find out as to how to implement the `IComparable` interface method `CompareTo` for a generic class.

I have a class called `BindingProperty<T>` which is used to create a `List<BindingProperty<intOrString>>` to bind to a `DataGrid`. The problem is that the I can not perform the Sort operation as the `IComparable` interface is not implemented by this `BindingProperty<T>` class. The result of comparison would depend on a data member 'Value' of the the `BindingProperty<T>` class where 'Value' is of Type T. When I click on the column header of the DataGrid, *I get an exception* that `CompareTo()` method is not implemented.

I would need help to implement this interface. Should I be using `IComparable<T>`? If yes, how do I do it?

Thanks in advance
Shakti

Comment: What is the Type of the generic List?

Comment: IList has been used to bind the DataGrid Columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up a generic type constraint on T.

```
public class BindingProperty<T> : IComparable where T : IComparable
{
    public T Value {get; set;}

    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
       if (obj == null) return 1;

       var other = obj as BindingProperty<T>;
       if (other != null) 
            return Value.CompareTo(other.Value);
       else
            throw new ArgumentException("Object is not a BindingProperty<T>");
    }
}
```

**Edit:**
Alternative solution to handle if value does not implement `IComparable`. This will support all types, just wont sort if they do not implement `IComparable`.

```
public class BindingProperty<T> : IComparable
    {
        public T Value {get; set;}

        public int CompareTo(object obj)
        {
           if (obj == null) return 1;

           var other = obj as BindingProperty<T>;
           if (other != null) 
           {
               var other2 = other as IComparable;
               if(other2 != null)
                  return other2.CompareTo(Value);
               else
                  return 1; //Does not implement IComparable, always return 1
           }
           else
                throw new ArgumentException("Object is not a BindingProperty<T>");
        }
    }
```

Comment: When I implement the above solution, I get an error message _"Error:The type 'System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Bally.UI.Framework.BindingProperty<T>'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage' to 'System.IComparable<System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage>'_." This is from another part of the project. The BindingProperty is being used as **BindingProperty<BitmapImage>**. Is there a way out?

Comment: The generic type must implement `IComparable` or you wont be able to sort on it. `BitmapImage` does not. And it does not make much sense to sort on a image.

Comment: I understand as to implementing IComparable is essential, but the other part of the code, (which is as part of the existing Framework), does have this BitmapImage as BindingProperty as a type.

Answer (score 0):

If the Type is a custom class, then your custom class needs to be IComparable.

e.g.

`List<FooClass>`, then `FooClass` needs to inherit/implement `IComparable`.

Comment: Thanks. But all the classes T can not not implement IComparable as some classes like BitmapImage, CustomCommands(implementing UICommand and has a member as BindingProperty<IList<CustomListViewUICommand>>) are not compatible. I am not sure what to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a generic constraint to require that `T` implements `IComparable<T>`. You can then compare two `BindingProperty<T>` instance by comparing their `Value` members. It is not clear to me if you need your class to implement `IComparable` or `IComparable<T>` but implemeting both is not much extra work.

```
class BindingProperty<T>
  : IComparable<BindingProperty<T>>, IComparable where T : IComparable<T> {

  public T Value { get; set; }

  public Int32 CompareTo(BindingProperty<T> other) {
    return Value.CompareTo(other.Value);
  }

  public Int32 CompareTo(Object other) {
    if (other == null)
      return 1;
    var otherBindingProperty = other as BindingProperty<T>;
    if (otherBindingProperty == null)
      throw new ArgumentException();
    return CompareTo(otherBindingProperty);
  }

}
```

Comment: When I implement the above solution, I get an error message _"Error:The type 'System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Bally.UI.Framework.BindingProperty<T>'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage' to 'System.IComparable<System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage>'_." This is from another part of the project. The BindingProperty is being used as **BindingProperty<BitmapImage>**. Is there a way out?